# Имя пакета в Nexenta

Tags: gcc, solaris, unix, linux

В связи с [вопросом](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/5776/linux-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-gcc-%D0%B2-nexenta), другой руководитель посоветовал удалить `gcc` через `apt`. Но на команду

```
apt-get --purge remove gcc
```

выдает следующее:

```
Reading package lists...Building dependency tree...Reading state information...Package gcc is not installed, so not removedYou might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:The following packages have unmet dependencies: libstdc++6-4.2-dev : Depends: g++-4.2 (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed                      Depends: gcc-4.2-base (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installedE: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Из этих сообщений

```
Package gcc is not installed, so not removed
```

следует, что пакет с `gcc` называется по другому. При этом `gcc` действительно установлен и в ответ на

```
gcc -v
```

выдает

```
Using built-in specs.Target: i386-pc-solaris2.11Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr/gcc/4.4 --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --with-gmp-include=/usr/include/gmp --with-gmp-lib=/usr/lib --with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/mpfr --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/lib --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=mt --enable-nls --enable-objc-gc --enable-libssp --libexecdir=/usr/gcc/4.4/lib --enable-c99 --with-pic --enable-wchar_t --mandir=/usr/gcc/4.4/share/man --infodir=/usr/gcc/4.4/share/info --build=i386-pc-solaris2.11Thread model: posixgcc version 4.4.4 (GCC)
```

Как узнать имя этого пакета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Использование: dpkg [<параметр> ...] <команда>Команды:-S|--search <шаблон> ...            Найти пакет(ы), которому(ым)dpkg -S gcc...
```

покажет пакеты в который есть gcc

```
aptitude search -V gcc
```

покажет пакеты в названии которых встречается gcc и покажет установлен ли пакет(i в первом столбце)

в твоём случае это наверное gcc-4.4

можно так удалить всё что начинается с gcc

```
apt-get remove --purge gcc*
```